# Running parallel http post requests in perl

Tags: perl

I need to use http POST request for multiple URL's in parallel using perl. What I need to change in the code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

@urls = ('http://url1.com:10001','http://url2.com:10002','http://url3.com:10003');

foreach (@urls)
{
   my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $_);
   my $resp = $ua->request($req);
}
```

This code is sending request in sequential. But I need to send the request in parallel to make the request faster. What we need to change in the above code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to create a thread for each of the connections.

Comment: Or if you don't want to go through the threads hassle, go async.  First search engine link: https://metacpan.org/module/KAORU/HTTP-Async-0.21/lib/HTTP/Async.pm You'll need to rewrite your code, though.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~msouth/ParallelUserAgent-2.61/lib/LWP/Parallel/UserAgent.pm

Comment: Thanks for the response. How I can capture the response of threads. Can you please share the code for the same? for example

Comment: @sanjiv The spirit of the site is more that you try out something first.  If really you're stuck, you can open a new question, but you're going to be asked to show some effort first (in the form of code).

Answer (score 0):

Execute each POST in a separate thread.  see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) for documentation

```
 use threads;
 my $t = threads->create(...);
```